# What is this excel method doing?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a code snippet right here:

```
public class ExcelUtils {
            private static XSSFSheet ExcelWSheet;
            private static XSSFWorkbook ExcelWBook;
            private static XSSFCell Cell;


    public static void setExcelFile(String Path) throws Exception {
            FileInputStream ExcelFile = new FileInputStream(Path);
            ExcelWBook = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFile);
        }

    public static String getCellData(int RowNum, int ColNum, String SheetName ) throws Exception{
            ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheet(SheetName);
             try{
              Cell = ExcelWSheet.getRow(RowNum).getCell(ColNum);
                 String CellData = Cell.getStringCellValue();
                 return CellData;
                 }catch (Exception e){
                   return"";
                 }
        }

    public static int getRowCount(String SheetName){
            ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheet(SheetName);
            int number=ExcelWSheet.getLastRowNum()+1;
            return number;
        }

    public static int getRowContains(String sTestCaseName, int colNum,String SheetName) throws Exception{
        int i;  
        ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheet(SheetName);
            int rowCount = ExcelUtils.getRowCount(SheetName);
            for (i=0 ; i<rowCount; i++){
                if  (ExcelUtils.getCellData(i,colNum,SheetName).equalsIgnoreCase(sTestCaseName)){
                    break;
                }
            }
            return i;
            }

    // this is the method that I have trouble understanding, and its purpose
    public static int getTestStepsCount(String SheetName, String sTestCaseID, int iTestCaseStart) throws Exception{
        for(int i=iTestCaseStart;i<=ExcelUtils.getRowCount(SheetName);i++){
            if(!sTestCaseID.equals(ExcelUtils.getCellData(i, Constants.Col_TestCaseID, SheetName))){
                int number = i;
                return number;
            }
        }
        ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheet(SheetName);
        int number=ExcelWSheet.getLastRowNum()+1;
        return number;
    }

}
```

I understand all the methods (except one) in the code, for example:
getCellData () returns the data in the specific row & column.
getRowCount () returns the number of rows in the sheet.
getRowContains () returns the row of a certain data.

The method I don't undertand is the last method "getTestStepsCount". I've tried reading it over and over again but I just don't get it. It seems really similiar to the getRowCount method, but at the same time not.

Can someone more experienced in code reading please help me get understand it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method is simply checking every line in a specified column of a specified Sheet.

Step by step:

**Method parameters:**

- String SheetName => name of the sheet in which your verification occurs
- String sTestCaseID => string which you are looking for
- int iTestCaseStart => number of line used as an offset for your search

**Steps of the method:**

1. For loop to do the search, return a result if found
2. If no result in the loop, then return another value

***Detail of Step 1:***

```
    for(int i=iTestCaseStart;i<=ExcelUtils.getRowCount(SheetName);i++){
        if(!sTestCaseID.equals(ExcelUtils.getCellData(i, Constants.Col_TestCaseID, SheetName))){
            int number = i;
            return number;
        }
    }
```

Here the `for` loop is iterating between your offset `iTestCaseStart` and the number of rows of your sheet.

For each row in this loop, it is checking if the data inside the cell at row `i` and column `Constants.Col_TestCaseID` is different than the value of `sTestCaseID`.

- If they are different, the method will get the index of the line (which is the value of `i`) as a result.
- If not, continue iterating

If no different value found before the last line, end of the loop, then step 2.

***Detail of Step 2:***

```
    ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheet(SheetName);
    int number=ExcelWSheet.getLastRowNum()+1;
    return number;
```

If entering step 2, the method will return the index of the last row + 1

**Additional comments**

There are many improvements that can be done in this code...

Comment: So it is basically returning how many times it can find "sTestCaseID" in the sheet?

Comment: Yes, if the offset is well populated.

Comment: In your opinion, would it be better to just loop though the whole sheet and increment a certain value if the ID is found, and basically return that?

Comment: It will depend on what you want exactly to do. Limiting to the line number is a good practice, but it would be better to use variables for example instead of repeatedly call some functions (like `ExcelUtils.getRowCount(SheetName)` )